# What is the fastest way to find a 4-field struct by its 3 fields in a collection?

Tags: c#, collections

If i have struct that contains

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int Id1;
    public int Id2;
    public string Name;
    public int ValueToFind;
}
```

how should i store and retrieve them? Only 2 options come to mind

1. put them in `List<MyStruct>` anhd loop until i find and break
2. store them in dictionary `Tuple<int, int, string>` as key and ValueToFind as value

The latter is not so handy because i would like to have them as that struct. Is there a collection that uses something like database indexes for 3 first fields for fast retrieval?

-matti

Comment: What about a customer `IEqualityComparer<MyStruct>` together with a dictionary? Unfortunately using that struct as both key and value increases memory overhead a bit. Personally I'd split them into two structs, one for the key, one for the value. Then assemble them into one struct once you have read the value.

Comment: thans! i gotta check it out. haven't heard about that.

Comment: There's no reason the dictionary couldn't map to the struct you need for convenience (just needs some more memory)

Comment: What about using HashSet (with equality comparer)

Comment: @SargeBorsch `HashSet`s aren't useful for lookups which the OP mentions he's doing pretty clearly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: why do i need IEqualityComparer if i split the struct I could use struct/tuple with only 3 first fields as key and (not struct) but simply ValueToFind as value.

Comment: If you split the struct, you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. If you don't split it, you should use `IEqualityComparer<T>` instead. As I said, I prefer the extra struct type for the key solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use a [`Dictionary<TKey, TVAlue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) with appropriate key. You can store structs in a dictionary. This gives you even fast retrieval and insertion (close to `O(1)`).

For such a simple structure you don't need a `Tuple`, try this:

```
public struct MyStructKey
{
    public int Id1;
    public int Id2;
    public string Name;
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStructKey Key;
    public int ValueToFind;
}
```

and then, for example:

```
static void Main()
{
  Dictionary<MyStructKey, MyStruct> d = new Dictionary<MyStructKey, MyStruct>();

  MyStruct ms = new MyStruct()
  {
    Key = new MyStructKey() { Id1 = 0, Id2 = 0, Name = string.Empty },
    ValueToFind = 4
  };

  d.Add(ms.Key, ms);

  Console.WriteLine(d[ms.Key].ValueToFind);
}
```

Alternatively you can use `Dictionary<MyStructKey, int>` not to have data duplication, and don't use `MyStruct` at all.

Comment: slow insertion is not an issue cause it's done only once for all items. but do u mean that I use struct as key? what would be the value?

Comment: I call BS on "slower insertion". Keeping an array-list or linked list sorted is pretty expensive.

Comment: @matti I didn't say to use struct as a key.

Comment: @millimoose Insertion into a sorted list is also `O(logn)`. Isn't it `O(nlogn)` for a dictionary?

Comment: Also, if the data structure changes frequently, I'd avoid the `List` method. Inserting into an array list is actually `O(n)` since you need to move on average half the list by one bucket on insertion. And you can't binary-search linked lists. (This is kind of why we have tree structures.) What it'd be good for is for a static data set that you populate and sort once, when you want zero memory overhead with fast enough lookup

Comment: @millimoose Well no, this is the case only when you exceed internal capacity. Typical case is `O(1)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx

Comment: @matti Appropriate means whatever suits you. It depends on how do you want to access your structures.

Comment: @BartoszKP That's `Add()`. To keep a list sorted, you need [`Insert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4.aspx): "This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count."

Comment: i just don't get it how this is an answer to my question. maybe i didn't make myself very clear. the question pretty much was how to use key and value....

Comment: i think i use Dictionary with Tuple of Id1, Id2, Name as key and ValueToGet as value... as I thought originally

Comment: @matti Well read the title of your question - it's asks about fast searching, not how to use key and values. Perhaps edit the question.

Comment: @BartoszKP: well u're sort of right. but thought that storing part of the question would involve what to put an where. But as I said I'll use Dictionary<Tuple<int, int string>, int>

Comment: @BartoszKP: well actually the title is "to find a 4-field struct by its 3 fields in a collection?" i thought that really asks what to use as a key in case of dictionary. but as nobody answered in the way i wanted it maybe it's not so well asked...

Comment: @matti Ok, I'll try to improve the answer.

Comment: @matti Is this what you intended to know about?

Comment: yes. Thanks! But isn't it waste of memory to have duplicate data (Id1, Id2, Name) both as key and value? or is it like the key is not stored entirely?

Comment: Overriding Equals would make it faster. Default implementation uses reflection which is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in hashtable-based types make it a little hard to lookup by something different than the exact key type. There is nothing about the theory of hashing that would prevent that from being possible, but it is not possible with the BCL at the moment.

To perform a lookup with the built-in `Dictionary` you need to provide GetHashCode and Equals methods for `MyStruct`. You will then need to pass in a partially filled instance of `MyStruct` that has the relevant three fields set and computes the hash code and equality result from them.

If you want a more elegant solution use a new struct as the lookup key:

```
public struct MyStructKey
{
    public int Id1;
    public int Id2;
    public string Name;
}
```

Put all items keyed on this new struct into a `Dictionary`. Make sure to override the equality and hash code providing methods.

Comment: You don't need to override equality and hash code providing methods in this case.

Comment: Right, if the default equality works and is fast enough for you. I see that rarely.